# I can't activate virtual environment

Tags: django, python-3.x, windows, environment-variables, virtualenv

Python 3.7.4
Windows 10
I've noticed that while creating new env I get:
`Error: Command '['P:\\test_env\\test_env\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 3221226505.` but it creates! Mb here is the problem
I made new virtual environment

`P:\learning_log\env`

But It seems like I cant activate it with:

`P:\learning_log\env>Scripts\activate.bat`

Just because there no such file named `activate.bat`
In `Scripts` I have only `python.exe` and `pythonw.exe`, I have already remade  environment for more then 10 times, searched in Net, so can't solve it, help me pls.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this problem in windows try to reinstall virtual environment or try another way to create a virtual environment.
one way to create a virtual environment is `virtualenvwrapper-win` package.
you can install this package using this command :

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

Then run to create a virtual environment:

```
mkvirtualenv <virtualenv name>
```

another way to create a virtual environment using `virtualenv` package.
you can install it using this command:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Then run to create a virtual environment:

```
virtualenv <virtualenv name>
```

Comment: Already solved the problem - reinstalled python and switch to the newest version